Flutter: Circular segmented percent indicator with 2 curves
Segmented Circular Percent Indicator
I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement this custom percent indicator. Can anyone please help me out in making this?
I found a package https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges but it doesn't provide me with different stroke for different ends of the same segment as shown in the screenshot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
